# How to query all channels names according to only orderer node

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I could query all channels' names using peer node.

**Is it practicable to query all channels' names using only orderer node, do not specify peer nodes?**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot query channel using ordering nodes, to query for channels you have to leverage [CSCC](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/scc/cscc/configure.go#L55) (Configuration System Chaincode) and invoke it against endorsing peer to receive list of the channels peer was joined to. Basically you need to use GetChannels API call. You can test it with peer cli command:

```
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0:7051 peer channels list
```